# Was Bilbo still on Ravenhill among the Elvenking's guard wearing the ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

When the eagles had not come yet and the battle seemed lost, Bilbo stood on Ravenhill among the Elves and saw Gandalf sitting on the ground in deep thought, preparing, he supposed one last blast of magic.

At that moment, was Bilbo still wearing the ring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; when he regains consciousness after the battle, he realises being invisible is why he wasn't found sooner:

> Then Bilbo remembered his ring! “Well I’m blessed!” said he. “This invisibility has its drawbacks after all. Otherwise I suppose I might have spent a warm and comfortable night in bed!” “It’s me, Bilbo Baggins, companion of Thorin!” he cried, hurriedly taking off the ring.

Comment: Then when he shouted "The Eagles! The Eagles!" he was also invisible.

Comment: "If the elves could not see him they could hear him."